# should (or shouldn't) I clean the ram when I closed all applications?

Tags: battery, ram, performance

This might be a bit of a general question but nevertheless:

Performance wise:
should I, when I kill all apps (or some of them) also clear memory?

I know that android keeps a stack of apps (Activities) to reuse and wipes them if memory if needed, but does it costs energy to keep those apps (which I currently don't need but might start up again) or do I clear the memory to have as much ram free as possible and is there a difference in battery load?

S.

Comment: Most types of RAM require power to maintain information, or at least require that values be refreshed, but I doubt that Android zeroes released memory or that the energy use is non-negligible.

Comment: To my knowledge, it takes the same energy keeping a bit set to 1 as it takes to keep it set to 0 – so if that's your concern, it should rather be negligible. It takes more energy to build up all the structures in RAM when you start that app again. Having "as much RAM free as possible" is as if you're saying you want your truck as empty as possible: unused RAM is a wasted ressource (check our [ram tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/ram/info) for details).